# Using nested ifs, an inner "else" is skipped while it should be evaluated, what am I missing?

Tags: python

I wanted to check if a "check.txt" file exists; if it exists then another `if` statement is executed, checking whether its contents matched an expected result then if not execute `else`. On the other hand if the outer if is evaluated as false, outer else should be evaluated. My problem is when the inner `if` is evaluated as false the outer `else` is evaluated instead of the inner `else`! it is skipped!

I used the following code:

```
def checht():

    if os.path.isfile("check.txt"):
        # creation_time = os.path.getctime("check.txt")
        # if (time.time() - creation_time) // (24 * 3600) <= 7:
        hold = os.path.isfile("check.txt")
        print(hold)
        f = open("check.txt", "r")
        print(f.readline())
        if f.readline() == sp2.find('span', class_="thetime date updated").get_text().strip():
            f.close()
            print("inner if")
            return "nothing is new"
        else:
            f.close()
            os.remove("check.txt")
            sys.exit()
            # create_file_and_status_update()
    else:
        print("in outer else")
        create_file_and_status_update()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but try removing `print(f.readline())`. Calling `.readline()` the first time gives you the first line. Calling it again gives you the second line, etc. This means that the line you print and the line tested inside the `if` statement are different lines.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code is incomplete, and you've shown no output to trace your problem.

Comment: Trying to follow your description is confusing.  Add a few more print statements so that every if/else has one at the top, and then show us the output.

Comment: @Omer, the file contained a single line though

Answer (score 0):

just tested, seems like you do not have the file "check.txt" so is always going to outer else

Comment: I have because look when I tried to print variable "hold" it returns true! so whats wrong?

Comment: @hanan can you post your output please

Comment: additionally when file contents matched to the expected result, inner "if" is evalauted correctly; but the problem is that when file "check.txt" contents is different from the expected result then outer "else" is evaluated instead of inner "else" hope you got the point.

Comment: here is the output I am getting True
last time updated 12/08/2019
in outer else

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets executed after

```
return "nothing is new"
```

line of code. Because the program gets out of the whole function. You also shouldn't use

`sys.exit`

at that point in the code either.

Edit:
please change your code like this and give us results of prints.

```
def checht():

if os.path.isfile("check.txt"):
    # creation_time = os.path.getctime("check.txt")
    # if (time.time() - creation_time) // (24 * 3600) <= 7:
    hold = os.path.isfile("check.txt")
    print(hold)
    f = open("check.txt", "r")
    firstLine= f.readline()
    searchfor = sp2.find('span', class_="thetime date updated").get_text().strip()
    print(firstLine)
    print(searchfor)       

    print(f.readline())
    if firstLine == searchfor:
        f.close()
        print("inner if")
        return "nothing is new"
    else:
        f.close()
        os.remove("check.txt")
        sys.exit()
        # create_file_and_status_update()
else:
    print("in outer else")
    create_file_and_status_update()
```

Because right now, I have no idea what

```
sp2.find('span', class_="thetime date updated").get_text().strip()
```

equals to in the context you posted.

Comment: There is no code that would be executed after the return anyway.

Comment: in that block; it is where problem I am experiencing it never be evaluated!

Answer (score 0):

Something appears wrong with your setup. If you run something like this, it behaves as you would expect, the "outter false" is never evaluated

```
if True:
    print('outter true')
    if not True:
        print('inner true')
    else:
        print('inner false')
else:
    print('outter false')
```

> outter true
>
> inner false